# summing up data form json and rendering it in html

Tags: jquery, json

I have a json data structured like that:

```
[
  {
    comment: "example",
    created_at: "2014-01-12T13:20:20Z",
    homepage: "http://example.com",
    name: "example",
    amount: 50,
   }
   {
    comment: "example2",
    created_at: "2014-01-12T13:20:20Z",
    homepage: "http://example2.com",
    name: "example2",
    amount: 150,
   }
   {
    comment: "example3",
    created_at: "2014-01-12T13:20:20Z",
    homepage: "http://example3.com",
    name: "example3",
    amount: 200,
   }
]
```

How should I sum up all amounts so as I can render the result in `<p class="total"> </p>` using jquery?

Comment: Be aware of the last comma of each object (behind amount), this would cause a parse error in ie < 9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Real easy:

```
var val = 0;
$.each(obj, function(){
    val += this.amount;
});
$(".total").html(val);
```

Where `obj` is your object.